# Find out if a node is an ancestor of another node for a tree stored as an adjacency list in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, tree, adjacency-list, ancestor

**The question**

I have a tree structure stored as an adjacency table (also known as a Naive Tree) in an SQL database. I wish to find out if node_b is an ancestor of node_a. How can I do this?

**Background details**

The table where the nodes are stored is defined as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE Nodes(
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
      parent INTEGER,     
      -- Other node specific data
      FOREIGN KEY (parent) REFERENCES Nodes(id)
    );
```

The tree depth is unknown, but in ordinary use cases is expected to be fairly small.

There are no loops in the tree.

Root nodes have a parent value of NULL. There may be multiple root nodes.

**Answer Criteria**

I'm looking for a query that is as fast as possible.

**Work done already**

I have come up with a solution which works, which I will post as an answer, but I would like to see if there is a better, simpler, quicker approach.

**Examples**

Given the following data set:

```
id     parent
1      NULL
2      1
3      NULL
4      1
5      2
```

- The query should return True (or 1) for node_a = 1, node_b = 1
- The query should return True (or 1) for node_a = 2, node_b = 1
- The query should return True (or 1) for node_a = 5, node_b = 1
- The query should return True (or 1) for node_a = 5, node_b = 2
- The query should return False (or 0) for node_a = 2, node_b = 3
- The query should return False (or 0) for node_a = 2, node_b = 5

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: @jarlh how would you suggest I format the data?

Comment: Write in proper columns. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

**My Solution**

The following query is the solution I used (`:node_a` and `:node_b` are placeholders for the node in question and its possible ancestor):

```
WITH RECURSIVE ancestors AS(
  SELECT parent, id=:node_b AS match 
  FROM NODES WHERE id=:node_a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n.parent, n.id=:id AS match
  FROM Nodes n JOIN ancestors
  ON ancestors.parent=n.id AND NOT ancestors.match
)
SELECT MAX(match) AS is_ancestor FROM ancestors;
```

**Explanation**

A common table expression is used to generate a query comprising the parent of each of the ancestors of node_a and whether that ancestor matches node_b

It starts with node_a itself, and checks whether that matches node_b, returning a row consisting of two columns `parent` and `match` - the direct parent of node_a and a boolean representing whether node_a matches node_b.

It then ascends up through the ancestors of node_a by recursively joining on the parent column, until either one of the ancestors matches node_b or the parent column is NULL.

If node_b is an ancestor of node_a then one row of this table will contain the value true for the match column.
If it is not then the match column will contain false for all rows. As true and false are represented as 1 and 0 respectively the MAX of the match column will be 1 in the first case and 0 in the second.

Therefore the whole query returns 1 if node_b is an ancestor of node_a and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. Anyway, how's the performance of your query? Say, in a tree with millions of nodes, and has depth of 1000 and above.